# jQuery custom event inside a for loop only triggering on the last iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a for loop, which iterates through objects found in JSON, to populate form fields.

With each object it finds, it will `.trigger('click')` the button which adds the required fields, ensuring there are the correct amount for the user to fill in.

The button that is triggered has a `.click()` function which appends a section to the form for each object found in the JSON, and the end of that function triggers a custom event, passing in the index of the JSON object `.trigger('delegateAdded', delegateIndex)`.

Finally, my event handler should `console.log` out each section added, using the index value we passed through earlier.

**Expected result (with 3 objects in the JSON in this example):**

1. for loop iterates over 3 objects, clicks button 3 times.
2. 3 form sections are appended to the form.
3. `'delegateAdded'` custom event is triggered **3 times**, console logging the indexes: **0, 1 & 2**

**Observed result (with 3 objects in the JSON in this example):**

1. for loop iterates over 3 objects, clicks button 3 times.
2. 3 form sections are appended to the form.
3. `'delegateAdded'` custom event is triggered **1 time**, console logging the final of the 3 indexes: **2**

**Here's my code for reference:**

```
var addDelegate = $('#add-delegate');
var delegateContainer = $('#additional-delegates');
var delegateHTML = $('#delegate-container');
var delegateNumber = 1;
var delegateIndex = -1;
var delegateData = $.parseJSON($('#delegateData').html());
var numberOfDeligates = delegateData.length;

// CLICK FUNCTION ON BUTTON
addDelegate.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    delegateNumber++;
    delegateIndex++;

    var delegateClone = delegateHTML.html();
    var delegateNewHTML = delegateClone.replace(/_delegateNumber_/g, delegateNumber).replace(/_delegateIndex_/g, delegateIndex);

    delegateContainer.append(delegateNewHTML);

    // TRIGGER CUSTOM EVENT
    $(document).trigger('delegateAdded', delegateIndex);

});

// ITERATE OVER NUMBER OF JSON OBJECTS
for (var i = 0, iDelegateNum = 2; i < numberOfDeligates;) {

    // TRIGGER BUTTON CLICK FOR EACH ITERATION
    addDelegate.trigger('click');

    // HANDLE CUSTOM EVENT FOR EACH ITERATION
    $(document).on('delegateAdded', function (event, dIndex) {
        console.log(dIndex);
    });
}
```

As it's only ever the final index that gets logged out, it's like the event gets overwritten with the newest one, but I don't think that's a thing, or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you are calling `addDelegate.trigger('click');` there's no `delegateAdded` event handler registered yet.

Also: I'm pretty sure you don't want to register 3 times the `delegateAdded` event handler. One is enough.

Move it out of the loop at the beginning of your code.